# The property windows.location.hash not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

```
        var isnav = '<%=Session("DisplayForm")%>'
        if (isnav != '') {

            window.location.hash = '#editform';
        } 

<a name="editform">&nbsp;</a>
```

This is my code. I tried to show the window on the anchor tag using location.hash. but the problem is after reload it is going back to the top of the page. the value Session("DisplayForm") is 1.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a string or a PHP script? `var isnav = '<%=Session("DisplayForm")%>'` Because right now it's a string.

Comment: @Lekoaf it's got nothing to do with PHP it's server-side Classic ASP code as is indicated by the tag [tag:asp-classic] in the question (but tbh it's irrelevant anyway).

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Got it mixed up with PHPs `<?` tag.